# A custom bash daemon progressively eating memory

Tags: bash, daemon

Hello I've written a keep-alive daemon that when run, spawns json-server and respawns json-server if its process is killed.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function start () {
    trap 'echo "Clean up and exit"; kill $js_pid; rm js_pid; exit' TERM
    exec > outfile
    exec 2> errfile
    exec 0< /dev/null

    while true; do
        (json-server --watch db.json --port 1234 &>/dev/null) &
        js_pid=$!
        echo $js_pid > js_pid
        wait $js_pid
        kill $js_pid &>/dev/null
    done
}

if [ "$1" != "__forked__" ]; then
        setsid "$0" __forked__ "$@" &
        exit
else
        shift
fi

# stop or start daemon

([ ! -f "js_pid" ] && js_pid=99999999999) || js_pid=$(cat js_pid) 

case "$1" in
    stop)
    killall simpled.sh
    ;;
    start)  
    if ! kill -0 $js_pid &>/dev/null
    then
        start
    fi
    ;;
    status)
    if kill -0 $js_pid &>/dev/null
    then
        echo -e "\njson-server running: pid $js_pid"
    else
        echo -e "\njson-server not running"
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo -e "\nsimpled.sh [start|stop|status]"
    ;;
esac
```

I've run this script on my hosting server and after a few days ssh connection became really slow, so I had to stop the daemon. I'm thinking it's because of the while true loop.

Can you help me make this script not to eat a lot of memory over time? Cheers!

Comment: That loop, at least by itself, shouldn't eat memory. I think you need to check the system status better next time it slows down to determine *why* it's slowing down (and if it's a memory problem, what process(es) are eating all the memory). I did notice one unrelated issue: the `js_pid=99999999999` won't work because the `( )` put it in a subshell. Just use a proper `if` `then` `else` statement -- trying to shortcut it with `&&` and `||` is just too easy to mess up.

Comment: what makes you think the root cause was this script? have you checked the `json-server` itself, maybe it's accumulating more data over time? P.S what is even a json-server?.. the name makes little sense, it's like calling something `xml-server`, or `text-server`..